# Adding a key value pair to an existing json object in perl

Tags: perl

I want to add a key value pair to a JSON object. Following is the structure of Param{Data} variable for the below code.

```
    $VAR1 = {
  'ArticleID' => '86',
  'OldTicketData' => {
       ...
  },
  'TicketID' => '67'
};
```

Following is the function in which I want to perform the mentioned operation:

```
sub PrepareRequest {
    my ( $Self, %Param ) = @_;
    my %TicketInfo = $Self->{TicketObject}->ArticleGet(
        ArticleID => $Param{Data}->{ArticleID},
        userID => $Param{Data}->{CustomerID},
    );

    my %newParamData = to_json($Param{Data});
    %newParamData->{'OldTicketData'}->{'Body'}=$TicketInfo{Body};

    return {
        Success => 1,
        Data    => %newParamData,
    };
}
```

Above function returns 'OldTicketData'. I want following key-pair attached to 'OldTicketData' element of the JSON object ->('Body', $TicketInfo{Body}). Consider, $TicketInfo{Body} returns a string 'someString'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is the wrong way around. You need to add the key to the hash reference first, before you turn it into JSON.

```
$Param{Data}->{'OldTicketData'}->{'Body'}=$TicketInfo{Body};
my $newParamData = to_json($Param{Data});
```

In addition, since `to_json` returns a string, which is scalar, you need to use `$newParamData` instead of `%newParamData`.

Of course you need to fix your `return` as well.

```
return {
    Success => 1,
    Data    => $newParamData,
};
```

Comment: Ooops. I got it mixed up with `from_json`. Your right @ysth.